# Yii - поиск по реляционным моделям с несколькими критериями

Tags: mysql, yii

Никак не получается задать условие поиска (использую MySQL Active Record)

Например, есть таблица авторов (Author) и таблица книг(Book), которые они написали.
У книг есть тематика (Category), например, комедии, боевики, детективы и тд.

Задача - нужно выбрать всех авторов, которые написали только комедии.
Прошу подсказать, как решить эту задачу с помощью Active Record

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи должны быть построены следующие реляции:

- Автор ко многим Книгам;
- Книга к одной Тематике.

Схема запроса будет следующая:

Выбрать всех Авторов, присоединить к ним их Книги, к Книгам - Категорию, отфильтровать по Категории.

Примерный код для реализации запроса:

```
Author::find()
        ->joinWith(['books', 'books.category'])
        ->andWhere([Category::tableName() . '.name' => 'Комедия'])
        ->all();
```

Comment: Это Yii 2? Вопрос больше по Yii 1.x
И данный код выберет всех авторов, у которых есть книга-комедия и не только. Но не выберет всех авторов, у которых есть ТОЛЬКО книги-комедии. В этом основная проблема была.

Comment: Во-первых: в таких случаях нужно всегда указывать версию Yii и вообще версию ПО, в противном случае используется последняя на данный момент. Во-вторых: перестаньте использоватьYii 1 и перейдите на последнюю версию. В третьих: никто, кроме авторов книг-комедий, в эту выборку не попадут.